# Usage of prepositions with the word "difficult"

Tags: prepositions

Just wanted to know if there are any rules on usage "to" or "for" with the word "difficult".

Comment: You're looking at it backwards. Prepositions are controlled by the predicate only within its own clause. In a complement clause, like _for me to understand you_ in _It's difficult [for me to understand you]_, the prepositions are controlled by the construction itself and don't depend much on whether the matrix predicate is the word _difficult_ or not.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, sir, that was pretty much informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult *to do* something

Difficult *for someone* to do something

Comment: Those are the rules for **all** infinitive complements: _for_ marks the subject, and _to_ marks the verb. If the infinitive subject is present with _difficult_ (or with most other non-verbal predicates that take infinitive complements, like _a pleasure, easy, common,_ or _interesting_), then it gets marked with _for_. The infinitive verb always gets marked with _to_ except in special cases, like modal verbs and sense verbs.